# How can you install DotNet4.0 with Chocolatey?

Tags: chocolatey

I thought I would create a file to install my favorite apps into a fresh Windows Server 2008 r2 SP1 install.

I got an error regarding .NET 4.0 and Nuget when trying to install the ChocolateyGUI, so I figured I would install .NET 4.0 instead with Chocolatey since it was listed in the gallery.

I still get the same error.

```
C:\Users\me>cinst DotNet4.0
Chocolatey (v0.9.8.20) is installing DotNet4.0 and dependencies. By installing y
ou accept the license for DotNet4.0 and each dependency you are installing.
Execution of NuGet not detected. Please make sure you have .NET Framework 4.0 i
nstalled and are passing arguments to the install command.
At C:\Chocolatey\chocolateyinstall\functions\Run-NuGet.ps1:52 char:10
+     Throw <<<<  $noExecution
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Execution of Nu...nstall comm
   and.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Execution of NuGet not detected. Please make sur
   e you have .NET Framework 4.0 installed and are passing arguments to the i
  nstall command.
```

Do I need to install .NET 4.0 into Windows manually before Chocolatey will work or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET framework 4.0 package is provided for package purposes and possible future consumers. You cannot install it with the current version of chocolatey as it is a prerequisite for chocolatey to have it installed already.

HTH